# How to fix warning init() is deprecated

Tags: ios, swift

For the code line:

```
let bytesDecrypted   = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>()
```

I am getting the warning: 
**'init()' is deprecated: init() will be removed in Swift 3.  Use `nil` instead**

What is the correct way to fix this warning?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do like this,

```
let bytesDecrypted: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int> = nil
```

Comment: At first it didn't remove the warning, but after a clean/build everything come back to normal. :)